# MAUI Shell Tabs Title Binding

Tags: maui

I'm brand new to MAUI and I've been using the new project template to create a basic setup that I can experiment with. It uses MAUI Shell out of the box.

The main page of the application is using Tabs and it works grand:

```
<TabBar>
   <Tab Title="Hello">
      <ShellContent... 
   </Tab>
   ... 
</TabBar>
```

But I cannot for the life of me get the Title to bind to the ViewModel. The ViewModel uses a single constructor in which DI provides a service registered at startup; like you would in a NET 7 app.

The compiler complains about the ViewModel constructor not having a parameterless constructor.

I've tried binding it like so:

```
<Tab BindingContext="{vm:TestViewModel}" Title="{Binding Title}"...
```

Is there a way I could get an instance of the ViewModel including the injected service into the constructor?

If you can't, how do you then change the tab title at runtime?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not easily possible. `BindingContext="{vm:TestViewModel}"` attempts to create a new instance of the `TestViewModel` and set the BindingContext of the Tab to that new instance, which you cannot do, because your ViewModel apparently doesn't expose a parameterless constructor. Shell Tabs only are aware of the page type that they are going to instantiate via their `ContentTemplate` property. They don't know what properties the page or its BindingContext expose. You would need to provide a property in a ViewModel that will be used as the BindingContext of the AppShell for this.

Comment: I think you could get the ViewModel instance in code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

As Julian pointed out, if you use that expression in xaml, it creates a new instance with parameterless constructor. But you use *Dependency injection* for viewmodel, then it would not work.

Thus, I recommend you set the *BindingContext* in code-behind file:

Since you use Dependency injection, that's a little different to get the instance you have added in startup. You could try using **ServiceProvider**.

*Here is partial code in **AppShell.cs***. Through this way, we successfully get the viewModel instance you added in ***MauiProgram.cs***.

```
IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

public AppShell()
{
    InitializeComponent();

#if ANDROID
    serviceProvider = MauiApplication.Current.Services;
#elif IOS || MACCATALYST
 serviceProvider = MauiUIApplicationDelegate.Current.Services;
#elif WINDOWS
 serviceProvider =  MauiWinUIApplication.Current.Services;
#endif
 this.BindingContext = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(TestViewModel)) as TestViewModel;      
}
```

In ***AppShell.xaml***, once we get the instance and set the BindingContext, we could use the bindings(`MyTitle` is a property in `TestViewModel`):

```
 <Tab Title="{Binding MyTitle}">
```

And in ***MauiProgram.cs***, here is an example to add a  ViewModel instance with IConnectivity service injected in.

```
    builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConnectivity>(Connectivity.Current);
    builder.Services.AddTransient<TestViewModel>();
```

If you still have any questions, feel free to ask me.

Hope it helps!